# Wordpress - "Add order" search client by phone number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site where I mostly get phone calls from people to place an order. My problem is that when I go to Woocommerce to "Add Order", I don't know if that client already exist unless I type his name. I have people that say their name as "Mike", next time as "Michael" etc so I have him on my list 2 times. Happens with other names too. I use "Create Customer on Order" plugin too so if the client does not exist I create him at that moment.

So my question is: Is there any way to add a code on the "Customer" field, after clicking on "Add order", so I can search a person by his phone number and not by his name?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress by default only allows you to search for users by username/nicename. You can of course build upon that and be able to search by first name, last name, email address and any custom user meta field that already exists in the user meta table.

Take a look at how they built this plugin: 
[Woocommerce - Better User Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-user-search/)

The main query they use to match users looks something like this:

```
            $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT user_id
                FROM (" . implode( 'UNION ALL', array_fill( 0, count( $terms ), "
                    SELECT DISTINCT u.ID AS user_id
                    FROM {$wpdb->users} u
                    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} um
                    ON um.user_id = u.ID
                    INNER JOIN {$mktable} mk
                    ON mk.meta_key = um.meta_key
                    WHERE LOWER(um.meta_value) LIKE %s
                    OR LOWER(u.user_login) LIKE %s
                    OR LOWER(u.user_nicename) LIKE %s
                    OR LOWER(u.user_email) LIKE %s
                    OR LOWER(u.user_url) LIKE %s
                    OR LOWER(u.display_name) LIKE %s
                " ) ) . ") AS user_search_union
                GROUP BY user_id
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= %d;
            ", $values ) );
```

Take a look at their source code, it's well commented and adjust it to your needs (if you only want to use phone), it's really simple. Just take the relevant content from better-user-search.php and import it to your themes functions.php or create your own plugin with inspiration from their work.

Comment: Thank you Bobeta. I will have a look on that